# Saving CoreGraphics drawing actions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

Is there some way I can do something like:

@implementation MyView

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   // Get the thing I'm supposed to draw (CGImageRef, pattern, etc.) and draw it
   // i.e. not real code
   CGContextDrawWhatever(self.objectThatHoldsDrawing.drawing);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `CGPathRef`, `CGLayer` (or maybe even just `CALayer`, but that's mostly equivalent to a `drawRect:` method) and rendering (e.g. buffering) to image context and just renderind the image.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was thinking of something liek that. Can you give me an example with CGLayer?

Comment: Have a look at http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_layers/dq_layers.html